# Is there an IPython (notebook) magic for Jython similar to Cython?

Tags: python, ipython, jython, cython, jupyter-notebook

I couldn't find any examples for Jython using IPython magic. Is this already possible?
For example, in an IPython notebook I can conveniently use the "magic" function for Cython so that I don't have to write the setup.py file and compile it manually. Can I do this also for Jython somehow? And if not, how would you run the following code best in an IPython notebook via Jython?

```
%load_ext cythonmagic

%%cython
def cy_lstsqr(x, y):
    """ Computes the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation. """
    cdef double x_avg, y_avg, temp, var_x, cov_xy, slope, y_interc, x_i, y_i
    x_avg = sum(x)/len(x)
    y_avg = sum(y)/len(y)
    var_x = 0
    cov_xy = 0
    for x_i, y_i in zip(x,y):
        temp = (x_i - x_avg)
        var_x += temp**2
        cov_xy += temp*(y_i - y_avg)
    slope = cov_xy / var_x
    y_interc = y_avg - slope*x_avg
    return (slope, y_interc)
```

Comment: You can run code in any interpreter that will read from stdin using `%%script jython` at the top of a cell. You just see printed output, though, it doesn't transfer variables to or from your notebook.